# Filtering data based on a top row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datepart

I have a set of period something like

```
PERIODID PERIODSTART PERIODEND   PRICE STARTDOW
1        2012-12-01  2012-12-10  10    6
2        2012-12-11  2012-12-20  20    -1
3        2012-12-21  2012-12-30  30    -1
```

Meaning that reservation in period 1 must start on saturday, but not for periods 2 and 3.

If I have a reservation from 2012-12-10 - 2012-12-15 I want to>
- filter periods for days (not a problem)
- check if reservation STARTS on saturday. Filter should be only for top (or first row) and I am not sure how to do that. If reservation does not start on saturday none of the rows should be returned.

I tried

```
select * from periods p
where 
((@ReservationStart between p.periodstart and p.periodend)
or 
(@ReservationEnd between p.periodstart and p.periodend))
and ((select top 1 datepart(weekday, startdow) from periods where p.hotelID = period.hotelID order by period.periodstart) in (@datepart(weekday, @ReservationStart), -1))
```

Is there a way to do it better, or to optimize code better for large amount of data?

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, not clear what you mean by the first row. First period of the reservation? Are you using this to test whether the reservation starts on the right DOW?

```
set datefirst 1 -- make Monday return 1 when calling datepart(day,...)

-- if reservation starts on STARTDOW, this will return a single row.
-- if not, it will return an empty record set
select top (1) * from periods p
where @ReservationStart between p.periodstart and p.periodend
  and p.STARTDOW in (-1, datepart(day,@ReservationStart))
```

EDIT

Maybe something like this then?

```
set datefirst 1 -- make Monday return 1 when calling datepart(day,...)

-- return all periods of the reservation
-- modify as necessary if you only want the first and last periods, as in your example.
select * from periods p
where p.periodend >= @ReservationStart
  and p.periodstart <= @ReservationEnd
  -- but only if the start date falls on an allowed DOW
  and exists (
    select * from periods p2
    where @ReservationStart between p2.periodstart and p2.periodend
      and p2.STARTDOW in (-1, datepart(day,@ReservationStart))
      and p2.hotelID = p.hotelID -- necessary correlation condition
    )
```

Comment: Yes, but I also want to a) return all the rows affected by reservation dates, b) check if the first row corresponding to reservation start date also corresponds to obligatory DOW (datefirst = row.DOW)

Comment: ok, so: return all periods of the reservation, but only if the start date falls on an allowed DOW, yes?